# Windows Phone 8.1 RT - AppBarButton icon problems

Tags: bitmap, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, appbar

I'm rendering Bitmap from Xaml snippet using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26184524/3853371 . Bitmap renders fine but when I try to set it as AppBarButton icon I get this: [image]

Rendered Image is made from Grid with 2 TextBlocks and it's not a rounded rectangle with an X in the middle.

```
<Grid x:Name="TodayIconImage" Height="41" Width="41">
      <TextBlock x:Name="dayTextBlock" Text="12" Style="{ThemeResource MessageDialogTitleStyle}"  FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
      <TextBlock x:Name="monthTextBlock" Text="Feb" Style="{ThemeResource MessageDialogContentStyle}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is what I'd expect if your original xaml is a rounded rectangle with an X in the middle. The circle border is added automatically and is not optional. For an X icon you can use the standard Cancel symbol. If you want a rectangular button then you can't use an AppBar but will need to create a custom UI.

You should use a solid-on-transparent image with the icon centred and enough padding for the AppBarButton's circle. The 240% scale version should have an 41x41 pixel icon with 18 pixels padding on all sides (see [Details on sizing, padding, scaling, and transparency for Windows Phone Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465302.aspx#details_on_sizing__padding__scaling__and_transparency_for_windows_phone_store_apps) in the [Guidelines for app bars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465302.aspx))

If your overall bitmap size is too large then it will be scaled down to fit. The padding still needs to be proportional.

Comment: I see that I didn't give enought information about my problem. Question is now edited.

Comment: Ok. The image you got was for an empty BitmapIcon.

The phone requires the BitmapIcon's UriSource be an ms- protocol URI not the raw path (Windows doesn't care). Updating the reference to ms-appdata:///temp/<filename> should fix the problem for you.