# Windows Phone 8.1 AppBarButton with custom BitmapIcon

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create a custom image for the AppbarButton.
I'm using code from
[Windows Phone 8.1 AppBarButton icon with 2 rows of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175156/windows-phone-8-1-appbarbutton-icon-with-2-rows-of-text/)

```cs
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await rtb.RenderAsync(TodayTextBorder);

IBuffer pixels = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();

string filename = "TodayIcon.png";
var outputFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var outputStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, outputStream);
    var dpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
    enc.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)rtb.PixelWidth, (uint)rtb.PixelHeight, dpi, dpi, pixels.ToArray());
    await enc.FlushAsync();
}

BitmapIcon icon = new BitmapIcon();
icon.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/" + filename);
TodayAppbarButton.Icon = icon;
```

But it doesn't work. Well, it works on the Emulator and on the phone in case the app was deployed directly from Visual Studio. But when I'm publishing app and installing it from the Store I'm getting erroneous appbar button image (like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9egT.png)